# CSS3 inline-Block doesn't work on fluid floating divs

Tags: css

I try to get all fluid elements after a line break in a row with vertical-align: top and display inline-block. But it doesn't work. The different height of the elements shoot the the layout after a line break.

Here is a sample [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3EF8g/)

**stylesheet:**

```
    section { 
        display: block;
        max-width: 720px;
    }

    img {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }

    .container {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .container:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }

    .col {
        float: left !important;
        margin-right: 3.3333333333333335%;
    }

    .t4 {
            width: 31.11111111111111%;
    }

    .t4:nth-child(3n) {
        margin-right: 0;
    }

    .p-item {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
```

**html5**

```
<section class="content">
    <div class="container inside">
        <div class="col t4 p-item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/225x300/01da90/fffedb" />
                <p>Brandname<br />This is a so such very very very long Productname i can't believe! This is a so such very very very long Productname i can't believe!<br />99.00 EUR</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col t4 p-item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/225x300/01da90/fffedb" />
                <p>Brandname<br />This is a so such very very very long Productname i can't believe!<br />99.00 EUR</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col t4 p-item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/225x300/01da90/fffedb" />
                <p>Brandname<br />This is a so such Productname i can't believe!<br />99.00 EUR</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col t4 p-item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/225x300/01da90/fffedb" />
                <p>Brandname<br />This is a so such very very very long Productname i can't believe! This is a so such very very very long Productname i can't believe!<br />99.00 EUR</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col t4 p-item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/225x300/01da90/fffedb" />
                <p>Brandname<br />This is a so such very very very long Productname i can't believe! This is a so such very very very long Productname i can't believe!<br />99.00 EUR</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col t4 p-item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/225x300/01da90/fffedb" />
                <p>Brandname<br />This is a so such very very very long Productname i can't believe!<br />99.00 EUR</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col t4 p-item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/225x300/01da90/fffedb" />
                <p>Brandname<br />This is a so such Productname i can't believe!<br />99.00 EUR</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col t4 p-item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/225x300/01da90/fffedb" />
                <p>Brandname<br />This is a so such very very very long Productname i can't believe! This is a so such very very very long Productname i can't believe!<br />99.00 EUR</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col t4 p-item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/225x300/01da90/fffedb" />
                <p>Brandname<br />This is a so such very very very long Productname i can't believe! This is a so such very very very long Productname i can't believe!<br />99.00 EUR</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col t4 p-item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/225x300/01da90/fffedb" />
                <p>Brandname<br />This is a so such very very very long Productname i can't believe!<br />99.00 EUR</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col t4 p-item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/225x300/01da90/fffedb" />
                <p>Brandname<br />This is a so such Productname i can't believe!<br />99.00 EUR</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Float will force block display on those elements, that's why they don't keep a line. Remove float and set parent's font size to zero (to avoid a space between inline blocks).

```
.inside {
    font-size: 0;
}

.col {
    float: none !important;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3EF8g/1/

Comment: Works good for me, even without font-size: 0. Which calls for the use of font-size: 0?

Comment: @user1154112 Line break between inline block elements will be displayed as a space character on screen. On some occasions you may get away without this hack. Read more: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/